# Entity Framework AutoMapper to DTO, do I need ForeignKey ID properties?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I've created an MVC project where I set up a business layer, and a data layer.
I'm using EntityFramework in the data layer, and was hoping to not have my DAL objects outside of the data layer. (Firstly, is this a good idea?)

I chose to use AutoMapper, and figured I'd create DTOs for my Entity Framework objects.
These would be passed through my business layer, to my front end, edited by the user in a form, and saved back through the business layer to the data layer.

I figure this *seems* like a good idea, and went about trialing it.

I figured my DTOs will need to keep their Primary Key IDs, but I could get away with excluding my ForeignKey ID properties (with the Column attribute), as I shouldn't use them in the other layers. (and I feel that exposing them in my DTO gives an opportunity for it to be manipulated incorrectly)

```
public class Player
{
    [Key]
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }        

    [Column("ClubId")]
    public int? CurrentClubId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CurrentClubId")]
    public virtual Club CurrentClub { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerDTO
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }        

    // notice CurrentClubId property doesn't exist in DTO
    public virtual Club CurrentClub { get; set; }
}

public class Club
{
    public int ClubId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ClubDTO
{
    public int ClubId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now what I find is, on the View for a form that edits a PlayerDTO, I need to fill a drop down with all available Clubs.

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PlayerObject.CurrentClub.ClubId, "Current Club")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PlayerObject.CurrentClub.ClubId, Model.Clubs)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PlayerObject.CurrentClub.ClubId)
    </div>
```

Note: model is a PlayerEditViewModel, containing a PlayerDTO property, 'PlayerObject'.

This will return a Club Id. But everything else about the Club is unknown.
So then I call save, and back in my data layer I set

```
Player PlayerObj = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Player>(PlayerDTOObj);
PlayerObj.CurrentClubId = PlayerDTOObj.Club.ClubId;
```

This seems a bit hacky, and I envision this snowballing. If Club has a Competition property, and each Competition has a Season....suddenly I'm having to worry about every ForeignKey in my data layer's Update method.

So to avoid this, should I stick to mapping my ForeignKey IDs?
Or can I continue to do this, but just generate custom property mapping for each ForeignKey Id? 
I don't feel like I need them until I end up in this scenario trying to do some sort of write back to the database.

Comment: data transfer object should be lightweight version of domain object, you dont have to create all properties in dto (including its FKs), unless it's needed in the ui

Comment: So would you go down the same path that I am, where I map the Foreign object (CurrentClub) but not the ID (CurrentClubId)? Editing it in a form, I need an ID...but displaying the content, I would need the object. (Without making extra calls back to the data layer).